# Collision Detection with Javascript, Canvas, and Alpha Detection

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection, sprite

I'm currently working on a basic javascript game that has two sprites that are not to be collided together.  However, basic bounding box collision won't suffice as there are portions of the sprites that are transparent and wouldn't 'count' as colliding.  I found a solution to the problem that I am having, but I can't get it to work.  What I would like to do is calculate the transparent portions of the sprites and make sure that if the transparent portions overlap, that there is no collision detected.  Here is what I found that solves the problem.

http://blog.weeblog.net/?p=40#comments

```
  /**
   * Requires the size of the collision rectangle [width, height]
   * and the position within the respective source images [srcx, srcy]
   * 
   * Returns true if two overlapping pixels have non-zero alpha channel
   * values (i.e. there are two vissible overlapping pixels)
   */
  function pixelCheck(spriteA, spriteB, srcxA, srcyA, srcxB, srcyB, width, height){
    var dataA = spriteA.getImageData();
    var dataB = spriteB.getImageData();

    for(var x=0; x<width; x++){
      for(var y=0; y<height; y++){
        if( (dataA[srcxA+x][srcyA+y] > 0) && (dataB[srcxB+x][srcyB+y] > 0) ){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

And for calculating the image data:

```
    /**
     * creating a temporary canvas to retrieve the alpha channel pixel
     * information of the provided image
     */
    function createImageData(image){
      $('binaryCanvas').appendTo('body');
      var canvas = document.getElementById('binaryCanvas');
      var ctx      = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var imageData  = [image.width];

      for(var x=0; x<image.width; x++){
        imageData[x] = [image.height];
        for(var y=0; y<image.height; y++){
          var idx = (x + y * image.width) * 4;
          imageData[x][y] = canvasData.data[idx+3];
        }
      }
      $("#binaryCanvas").remove();
      return imageData;
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement this solution, or if this is the best solution to my problem.  Is this what I'm looking for?  And if so, where do I put these methods?  The thing that I'm most confused about is what I should be passing to spriteA and spriteB.  I've tried passing Images and I've tried passing the imageData returned from the `pixelCheck` method, but receiving the same error: that the object or image `has no method 'getImageData'`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are wrong with this.

You made a function:

```
function createImageData(image){...}
```

But what you are calling is:

```
spriteA.getImageData();
spriteB.getImageData();
```

The dot notates a property of an object. You were trying to call a function that was never part to the objects. There are some simple fixes.

add the createImageData() function to your constructor :

```
function Sprite(){
    ...
    this.createImageData = function(image){...};
    ...
}
```

or :

```
Sprite.createImageData = function(image{...};
```

or just call it correctly:

```
createImageData(spriteA.image); // or whatever the image is
```

Second, your function calls for an image parameter, but you aren't supplying one. Simply remember to supply the image when you call it. You could also remove the parameter and get the image from within the function.

Sort of like this:

```
function Sprite(){
    ...
    this.createImageData = function(){
        var image = this.image;
        // or just use this.image, or whatever it is
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Also. I forgot to mention that appending the new canvas element to the body is unnecessary. You can just use `var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');` It all works the same otherwise. Just omit the `$("#binaryCanvas").remove();`